# excel:compare 2 columns and copy data on other columns

Tags: excel

need help.. i trying to compare 2 columns and copy data in other columns..

```
Columns: 

A     B     C     D
1     3     10
2     4     20
3     1     30
4     2     40 
5     0     50
```

i want to compare column A to B to find its duplicate and copy data from column C if column A has a duplicate at column B...

Result must be:

```
A     B     C     D
1     3     10    0
2     4     20    40
3     6     30    10
4     2     40    20  
5     0     50    0
```

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer as I understand the question (assuming the change in `col B` is just a typo):

Input

```
A   B   C   D
1   3   10  
2   4   20  
3   6   30  
4   2   40  
5   0   50
```

Output

```
A   B   C   D
1   3   10  0
2   4   20  40
3   6   30  10
4   2   40  20
5   0   50  0
```

Formula in `D2` (filled down): `=IF(COUNTIF(B$2:B$6, $A2)>0, VLOOKUP($A2,$B$2:$C$6, 2, FALSE), 0)`.

`COUNTIF(B$2:B$6, $A2)` returns the number of times the value in `A2` appears in the array `B2:B6`. If this value is greater than `0` (meaning that `A2` **is** in `B2:B6`), the `IF()` function looks looks up `A2` in `col B` and returns the value in the 2nd row (`col C`); if `A2` is *not* in `B2:B6`, the formula returns `0`.